# make :before not clickable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an image uploader. I have a drag and drop field for the image using https://codecanyon.net/item/slim-image-upload-and-ratio-cropping-plugin/16364167?ref=pqina&ref=pqina&clickthrough_id=749572872&redirect_back=true . But I want the dropzone to have an image as an overlay of the dropzone. I managed to do this with a :before element. It works as intended in Chrome and even in Edge. But in Firefox I can't click the dropzone behind the :before Element. Is there any way to fix that?

Very simplified example here:

Simplified :before:

```
.dropper:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  opacity: .5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6kv6u9kv/

I want the "click me" to be clickable. I appreciate any quick help because this is for work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

You can use `pointer-events: none;` css property in your overlay.

> The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements
>   respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states,
>   click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is
>   visible.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.dropper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aaa;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.dropper:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  opacity: .5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropper">
  <a href="#" id="click">
  click me
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg you the boss, it works! I feel so dumb right now as the answer was so easy to accomplish. Thanks man! Will mark the answer as correct in 8 min.

Comment: "A fool thinks himself to be wise, but a wise man knows himself to be a fool." - W. Shakespeare... Make sure to check out the browser support for pointer-events [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) style to tell the browser to, as the name suggests, ignore any pointer events. This includes blocking pointer events to elements it may cover.

```css
.dropper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aaa;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.dropper:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  opacity: .5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropper">
  <a href="#" id="click">
  click me
  </a>
</div>
```

Of course check the browser support. If you are targeting a browser that does not support it you would have to implement some forwarding system: capture the click on `.dropper` get the mouse x,y and for any element occupying the same coordinates trigger the event for that element.

Answer (score 1):

`pointer-events: none` is an obvious choice though has less browser support.

Here is another way

```css
.dropper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aaa;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropper:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
}
.dropper a {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropper">
  <a href="#" id="click">
  click me
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try both solutions in my browsers and see which works best!

Comment: @kingardox This one will work on IE8/9/10 which `pointer-events` won't